# Visual of a clustered data

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a datasets ( I wanted to find which countries belong to optimum clusters) ;  I clustered( 5 clusters) based on one of the legit columns .... at the end I appended the labels to the original data frame ; but don't know how to make it visually appealing for the sake of understanding which country belongs to which label in a visual way .

[image: final part of my labeling]

it is written in Jupiter environment; If it's needed inform me below

Notes :
"OCC1991" is my main data frame ; I created